# A more aesthetic way of copying an object literal?

Tags: javascript

This is client side. Webpack, Babel and Babel Imports.

My project has a folder called "models" which contains object literals as definitions of the expected JSON results from endpoints.

The objects only contain strings, ints, booleans and arrays/objects which contain those data types

eg:

```
{
    name: "String"
    age: 35,
    active: true,
    permissions: [
        { news: true }
    ]
}
```

When I want to use a model definition, in order to ensure I don't have issues with references, I must use:

```
let newObject1 = Object.assign({}, originalObj )
```

or

```
let newObject2 = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( originalObj ))
```

I find this a bit ugly and it pollutes my code a bit.

I would love the ability to use the `new` keyword on object literals, but of course that's not a thing.

```
let clone = new targetObj
```

What's the most aesthetic way to handle the cloning of an object literal without creating a reference?

Comment: Wait why do you have *both* of those?

Comment: You ask about cloning object *literals*, but give an example with an object *variable*. (2) Note that the two methods you present, produce different things, e.g. when the objects are deeply nested, or contain other than plain objects (e.g. Date objects).

Comment: Excuse my inexperience.

The objects I am trying to copy are only going to have strings, numbers, booleans and objects/arrays contains those datatypes - coming from JSON, so no functions or date objects.

Comment: What do your models look like? Could you post an example? It sounds like you could use factory functions or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript way of implementing such object "templates" are constructors:

```js
function Original() {
    this.name = "String";
    this.age = 18;
    this.active = true;
    this.permissions =  [
        { news: true }
    ];
}

var obj = new Original();

console.log(obj);
```

Or, in ES6 `class` syntax:

```js
class Original {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "String";
        this.age = 18;
        this.active = true;
        this.permissions =  [
            { news: true }
        ];
    }
}

let obj = new Original();

console.log(obj);
```

Be aware that `Object.assign` will only create a shallow copy, so it would not copy the `permissions` array, but provide a reference to the *same* array as in the original object.

```js
const originalObject = {
    name: "String",
    age: 35,
    active: true,
    permissions: [
        { news: true }
    ]
};

let obj1 = Object.assign({}, originalObject);
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, originalObject);

// change a permission:
obj1.permissions[0].news = false;
// See what permissions are in obj2:
console.log(obj1.permissions);
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question and sheds light on things I didn't know to ask about.

I didn't realise that about Object.assign. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
const model = () => ({
    name: 'string',
    age: 20,
    array: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
});

let newObject = model();
```

You won't have the pleasure of using `new` - see trincot's answer for that - but you don't have to worry about nested objects (`assign`) or feel gross (`stringify + parse`).